# Running a BAT file from ANT

Tags: ant, automation, batch-file

I have gone through number of posts on the very forum but couldn't sort it out. I am trying to run a BAT file from ANT script. The folder hierarchy is like this

```
- Project
| - build.xml
| - build-C
| | - test.bat
```

The ANT file that i wrote so for is

```
<project name="MyProject" basedir=".">
    <property name="buildC" value="${basedire}\build-C" />

    <exec dir="${buildC}" executable="cmd" os="Windows XP">
        <arg line="/c test.bat"/>
    </exec>
</project>
```

The bat file content is

```
echo In Build-C Test.bat
```

It says that build failed .. :s i dun know what wrong am i doing ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<property name="buildC" value="${basedire}\build-C" />
```

This should be `${basedir}` I guess? Use

```
<echo>${buildC}</echo>
```

to make sure the dir is correct.

And shouldn't

```
<exec dir="${buildC}" executable="test.bat" os="Windows XP" />
```

do the job?

Comment: Thanks ... I figured otut hat mistake but now i am stuck at **Execute failed: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: test.bat error=2**

Comment: Thsi helped.
 <exec dir="${buildC}" executable="cmd" os="Windows XP">
  <arg line="/c test.bat"/>
 </exec>

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help expand on the already given/accepted answers:

I suggest executing `cmd` with the batch script as a parameter:

```
<exec failonerror="true" executable="cmd" dir="${buildC}">
  <arg line="/c &quot;${buildC}/test.bat&quot;"/>
</exec>
```

Not sure if it is necessary to use the absolute path `&quot;${buildC}/test.bat&quot;` since `dir` is specified, but I put it just in case. It might be enough to use `/c test.bat`.

My project executes a batch script on Windows operating systems & a shell script on all others. Here is an example:

```
<target name="foo">
  <!-- properties for Windows OSes -->
  <condition property="script.exec" value="cmd">
    <os family="windows"/>
  </condition>
  <condition property="script.param" value="/c &quot;${basedir}/foo.bat&quot;">
    <os family="windows"/>
  </condition>
  <!-- properties for non-Windows OSes -->
  <property name="script.exec" value="sh"/>
  <property name="script.param" value="&quot;${basedir}/foo.sh&quot;"/>

  <echo message="Executing command: ${script.exec} ${script.param}"/>

  <exec failonerror="true" executable="${script.exec}" dir="${basedir}">
    <arg line="${script.param}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```