# ant build include batch file content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: batch-file, ant, cmd

I have an ant build that includes my batch file called `launcher.cmd`:

`<include file="${basedir}/src/com/project/files/launcher.cmd" />`

When I try to run my build it fails with the error: `src\com\project\files\launcher.cmd:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Searches are telling me that it is parsing my file as xml which causes it to fail, so my question is how do I give my include file a file type for ant to parse with?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. The `include` task can only be used to include another Ant build script in the current one. It does not understand anything about any other file format.

Comment: @greg-449 sorry I am completely new to working with these build scripts. I am trying to include a batch file in my Adobe flex desktop application to then call while the user is running the application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include "batch" using  tag. It is for [including](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html)  another ***build file***

To run a batch file  try the [exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task.  Some details here in another SO question: [Running a BAT file from ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616287/running-a-bat-file-from-ant)

Your code will be something like below:

```
<exec dir="${buildC}" executable="${basedir}/src/com/project/files/launcher.cmd"   />
```

Comment: Thank yo for the answer. I don't want to execute the batch file on building , I want to be able to execute the batch file at some point during execution. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  Please see the documentation. The file is read before execution

Comment: I will look into this hopefully tomorrow. If it works as expected I'll accept answer